# Payments, shopping basket and add item to basket only for half hour

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, store

Here is a site, which after clicking "Dodaję" (means "add" in polish language) item goes to basket for 30 minutes: https://remix.pl/

While the item is in a basket, the item can not be purchased by others. I checked their basked: when I removed cookies, items were removed from basket (so the basket uses php session) and items were again available to buy.
I would like to know how did they do that (does their basket use **database** to store date time of added item to count 30 minutes or the script can be done another way?).
Maybe it is a **Cron Job** or something?
What is the best way to do it via php or it is impossible to do something like that with php? I do not mean displaying time ticking/passing, because it need some jQuery, js etc. but just the essence of the script.

I ask about it, because I made an online store for the client, who sells used clothes like that remix.pl so the item quantity is always 1. I have to make some blockade for products, which are added to basket by one user to  add the same item for another one user.
I do not have mind how to do it.

And here is another one question: Is it possible to remove item quantity only then, when the item is paid via paypal for example?
Chemistry for example:
Item quantity: 99
After adding to basket: still 99
After placing an order to MySQL database: still 99
After paid by paypal for example: 98
Is it a good practice and is it possible to run a script after the item is paid?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a basket table in your database as well. When sy places an item in his basket, insert a record into the basket table as well, along with a timestamp of the entry. When you query the products table, you consider those products unavailable, which are in the basket table and the timestamp value is less than 30 mins old. You can ignore any reservations in the basket, which are older than 30 minutes. You can clean up the basket table from either a scheduled script or from any regularly run page's code.

Regarding your 2nd question: of course you only deduct the sold product quantity from stock when the payment is successfully completed. Paypal api provides callback for that, see [instant payment notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

Comment: I probably found the best way to do it: When user add 1 item to basket then decrease the item's quantity by 1 for 30 minutes. If item is paid withing that 30 min, then decrease that quantity forever, if item is not paid within 30 min, then increase the quantity by 1. That way I can sell used products that have quantity 1 and new products that have quantity 999. 
If quantity of item was 1 and now is 0 then user cannot buy item, if a quantity of item was 999 and now is 998 then user just can buy 998 items. the quantities of items are increased everytime when user didnt pay within 30 min

Comment: I have a problem, what if someone buy 1000 items with 999 quantity? For example a bot program? Then I will not have products on my site for 30 minutes. The program buys a product every 30 minutes so my shop always have 0 quantity. Looks so ugly.

Comment: Maybe I should not have a quantity. Just products.

Comment: Because If I have in my shop product with for example 99 quantity, someone can reserve all 99 pieces and then other people will not have a chance to buy it for 30 minutes. I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can't really, unless you impose a limit on how many products a user can buy. The other options are that you either do not reserve the products in the basket or reservation period is much shorter. The common thing between these solutions is that these have nothing to do with programming. This is pure business logic, so pls use your common sense and business acumen.

Comment: Moreover, this problem was **not** in the original question. So, it is unfair to expect an answer to provide a response to sg that was not even asked!

Comment: i wonder how it is made on for example amazon.com. someone adds a product to a basket and then some other add the same product too, but one of them paid for the product, so the other one can not buy it but it is still in his basket, lol

Comment: ok i will accept the answer, but the topic should be deleted then.